# what is wrong with my GPA calculator? (Javascript)

Tags: javascript

These are my codes for gpa calculator. I can get the gpa for first module correctly, however, it does not work anymore if i add the second module. Can someone help me?

```
function calculate(){

        var credit1 = document.getElementById('credit1').value;
        var grade1 = document.getElementById('grade1').value;
        var module1 = credit1 * grade1;

        var credit2 = document.getElementById('credit2').value;
        var grade2 = document.getElementById('grade2').value;
        var module2 = credit2 * grade2;

        var credit3 = document.getElementById('credit3').value;
        var grade3 = document.getElementById('grade3').value;
        var module3 = credit3 * grade3;

        var credit4 = document.getElementById('credit4').value;
        var grade4 = document.getElementById('grade4').value;
        var module4 = credit4 * grade4;

        var credit5 = document.getElementById('credit5').value;
        var grade5 = document.getElementById('grade5').value;
        var module5 = credit5 * grade5;

        var credit6 = document.getElementById('credit6').value;
        var grade6 = document.getElementById('grade6').value;
        var module6 = credit6 * grade6;

        var tmodule = module1 + module2 + module3 + module4 + module5 + module6;
        var tcredits = credit1 + credit2 + credit3 + credit4 + credit5 + credit6;
        var gpa = (tmodule / tcredits).toFixed(2);

        document.getElementById("gpa").innerHTML = gpa;
    }
```

Comment: Show us your html. Or rather add your code (including html) on https://jsfiddle.net/ to make it easier to answer your question.

Comment: Can you post a complete example of a page that demonstrates the problem? Also, tell us what the expected results are and what you actually get. I mean, I made a fiddle, and it seems to work fine...

Comment: @NickDeBeer Thanks, sorry am new to stackoverflow so i'm not familiar with the procedures of asking questions. :) Here is my jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/3x2jjhLo/1 (the gpa is supposed appear beside the calculate and reset buttons. For some reason the css is also messed up - because i used %?) Expected results - if I enter A for all my modules of 6 credits, I would expect to get a 4.0 but it's not turning out that way

Comment: @MrLister ^ as above

Comment: The problem with the fiddle is that you had the javascript set to onload, which meant that the calculate function was not visible in the global scope. So I changed the settings to "no wrap - in head" and now it works. That is, it prints 0.00 (or if you remove the tofixed, 0.000216000216000216) rather than the 4 you expected. http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/3x2jjhLo/2/ I don't know what the calculation really should be.

Comment: @MrLister Thanks! But the calculation is still wrong. For example, it should just read the columns that have values in it. so if i have credits of 4 for every module and an A for all, it should show 4.00. Or if it was B+ for everything, it should show 3.50

Comment: @Yiting That's why I said I don't know what the calculation really should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mr Lister said, change the settings to "no wrap - in head" or your javascript will not run. Then, you have to convert your values to numbers:

```
var credit1 = Number(document.getElementById('credit1').value);
```

or this:

```
var tcredits = credit1 + credit2 + credit3 + credit4 + credit5 + credit6;
```

will concatenate strings.

**Edit:**
Note that you don't need to do that for grades or modules because of those lines:

```
var module1 = credit1 * grade1;
```

Operator* works on number, not strings.